Please explain Figure 24.4 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
I am reading the proof of Theorem 24.4.
I don't understand Figure 24.4.
Is the solid enclosed by the red closed curve in Figure 24.4 $A\cap N$?
Is the blue surface in Figure 24.4 $A\cap M$?
Why is the image by $F$ in Figure 24.4 a rectangular parallelepiped?



Yes, the blue surface is $A \cap M$ and the solid enclosed by the red closed curve $A \cap N$.
The image of $F$ doesn't have to be rectangular, but you can always achieve this by restricting the diffeomorphism $F$, so that $B$ is rectangular.
